# Can't import keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I can't run keras; when I try to import keras from a Jupyter notebook I first see

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
```

in red, but then the kernel crashes and I see a prompt with:

```
Kernel Restarting
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

If I try to run it directly with python (so I have a file called run.py that just imports keras) I get:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Illegal instruction: 4
```

I am on High Sierra (10.13.2) on a mid 2012 Macbook with a 2,9 GHz Intel Core i7 processor. I have python 3.6 installed on the latest conda and I am also running the latest versions of keras and tensorflow.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have the same problem and installing mxnet-mkl library didn't help. Are you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please see my comment on the answer below. My problem was a messed up python and pip installation that installed packages in weird places...

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `mxnet-mkl` library and then run keras.

Please see link below:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/8183

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When installing the package you suggested I found out that pip was installing the packages in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages, while I was running R (and pip itself is installed) in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages. I manually moved all packages to the new directory and the problem was solved.

Comment: Should I erase my question?